# Multiple If conditions with Vlookup and IFNA involved

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, vlookup

I am scratching my head and just cannot find the solution for hours. I need the excel to use Cell D(this is the result from another Vlookup) as the result OR Cell A + Cell B as the other result based on the following. (Not really expert with Excel, but do Understand some logic)

1. if vlookup from column y return " ", then Vlookup another table to get result of CELL D(Show " "if this Vlookup is #N/A)
2. if Vlookup from column y return #N/A, the Vlookup another table to get result of Cell D (Show " " if this Vlookup is #N/A)
3. if Vlookup from column Z return " ", the Vlookup another table to get result of Cell D (Show " ",if this Vlookup is #N/A)
4. if  Vlookup from column Z return #N/A, the Vlookup another table to get result of Cell D (Show " "if this Vlookup is #N/A)

if any if the above returns other than " " or #N/A, then just do CELL A + CELL B = Cell D

Here is an attempt but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
=if(and(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,16,false)<>""),F18-E18,
 if(and(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,14,false)<>""),F18-E18, 
 if(and(IFNA(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,16,false))=false),F18-E18, 
 if(and(IFNA(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,14,false))=false),F18-E18,
 "another Vlookup" ))))
```

Note: Edited in as OP does not have edit rights. Line-breaks added to formula for legibility.

Comment: This doesn't seem too difficult. What have _you_ already tried? You are more likely to obtain help here with an effort of your own.

Comment: one by one it is not that difficult, but when I combine them together, it becomes really hard, too many (). if I close it wrong, it stuffs up the whole thing. Result either error, or wrong result

Comment: =if(and(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,16,false)<>""),F18-E18,
if(and(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,14,false)<>""),F18-E18,
if(and(IFNA(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,16,false))=false),F18-E18,
if(and(IFNA(vlookup(A18,DEALS!A:P,14,false))=false),F18-E18,"another Vlookup"
))))       this doesnt work

Comment: You reference `column y` and `column Z`, but neither of these appear in your attempt.  Where are they?

Comment: I made it simple to explain my question. Column y is the column no 14 from the vlookup table and column z is the column 16 from the vlookup

Comment: below seems to work, but when it shows #n/a when it the lookup cannot find nothing, but I have already command to show " ", if #N/A

Comment: =if(or(index(DEALS!N:N,(match(A19,DEALS!A:A,0)))="",ifna(index(DEALS!N:N,(match(A19,DEALS!A:A,0))),true),""),ifna(vlookup(A19,DEALS!A:C,2,false),""))